# How to create bones using world matrix

Tags: scripting, bones

I am writing an importer of a new file format, which using a 4x4 world matrix to define bones
now I am using the 4th row column 1-3 to define the head of bone and the distance to the child's head to define the length of the bone. then the tail of the bone is calculated by

`bone.tail = bone.head + Vector((bone_length,0,0)) * bone_world_matrix.to_3x3()`

this can build the correct shape of the skeleton but the mirrored axis was missing
how can I using this data correctly? OR is there any python API can directly use the world matix when creating bones?